# flutter problem : How to convert this type of double from string?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

I want to convert sting to double ,
here my double is saperated by comma,
So how to do it?

```
void main() {
  var myInt = int.parse('12345');
  assert(myInt is int);
  print(myInt); // 12345
  print(myInt.runtimeType);  // int
  
  
    var myDouble = double.parse('1,230.45');
  assert(myInt is double);
  print(myDouble); 
  print(myDouble.runtimeType); // double
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to remove `,` first to parse it as double:

```
var myDouble = double.parse('1,230.45'.replaceAll(',', ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the comma before parsing it.
to remove comma you can use replaceAll on Stirng like this

```
void main() {
  var k1 = '1,230.45';
  var k2 = k1.replaceAll(',','');
  var myDouble = double.parse(k2);
  print(myDouble); 
  print(myDouble.runtimeType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`package:intl`'s [`NumberFormat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) also can parse numbers with commas as grouping separators:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var numberFormat = NumberFormat('#,###.##');
  var myDouble = numberFormat.parse('1,230.45');
  print(myDouble); // Prints: 1230.45
  print(numberFormat.format(myDouble)); // Prints: 1,230.45
}
```